# Text underneath the android checkbox

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I'm aware that we can have a Checkbox with an independent textView underneath it, but can we have a text that is part of a checkbox appearing it underneath the checkbox box?

If yes, can it be achieved through Android UI instead of doing it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using `CheckedTextView`:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/checkmark"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Checked text"/>
```

And a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" android:state_checked="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checked"></item></selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I started with what you suggested. Is it possibile to have a filling box instead of a check mark? so once the user clicks on the box, instead of having a check mark, it will be a box filled with a color.

Comment: Yes you can use custom drawables in your selector.